# Flutter build apk not showing images or icons

Tags: flutter, image, build, apk, release

I have made a Flutter project and everything works just fine, previously I have tried it many times on the apk as well, and everything was fine, but when I tried it recently building the apk, it didn't show any icons or images in the application on the apk. And the icons also have turned to a Chinese language style symbols.

Note: Everything works perfectly fine still on an emulator, but not on apk release version.

Need help to fix it. Thanks

My pubspec.yaml:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get: ^4.6.5
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.7
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.1
  round_icon: ^0.0.4
  searchfield: ^0.7.5
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.4
  dotted_line: ^3.1.0
  syncfusion_flutter_sliders: ^21.1.37
  floating_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.5.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/splash_screen.png
  color: "#D45555" 

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have same problem on one page. did u find any solution?

Comment: @AmirKeshavarz I sent my code to someone else, and they built the apk from their system, and it worked completely fine. Idk what was the issue with my system that suddenly this issue occured.